# Get the largest discounts using sql query

Tags: mysql

I have a lot of products in my table. Some of products has a discount, so in `price_old` field is given old price of the product, and the `price` field has a new discounted price.

Is it posible to get all products, arranged by the biggest difference(discount) between fields `price_old` and `price`?

Comment: Biggest by value or percentage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
ORDER BY price_old - price DESC
```

The record having the *biggest* `price_old - price` difference will be returned first, followed by the record having the second biggest difference, etc.

Comment: can I add here some additional `WHERE` conditions? Thanks!

Comment: @Gediminas Yes, of course. The filtered result set will be returned order by the difference of the prices.

Answer (score 0):

```
select product,price,price_old
from table_name
order by (price_old-price) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need `order by biggest discounted product`. And you'll need to find discount % for that.

I don't find any answer covering the scenario so I am posting one here:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    ((price_old - price)/price_old)*100 as 'Discount (%)'
FROM products
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use like this to see how much discount was

```
  Select *, (price_old-price) as diff from tablename order by diff desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    *, old_price-price discount, (old_price-price)/old_price percent 
from 
    product 
order by 
    discount 
desc;
```

the place in discount can be replaced with percent to show the discount percentage.